# XML to XSLT Conversion

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to  two xml file  i want to convert below xml in xslt how  we can convert those in XSLT

Input Xml:

```
<Order OrderNo=”1234567890”>

 <OrderLines>

  <OrderLine PrimeLineNo=”1” SubLineNo=”1”/>

  <OrderLine PrimeLineNo=”2” SubLineNo=”1”/>

 </OrderLines>
</Order>
```

Output Xml:

```
<Order OrderName=”1234567890”>

 <OrderLines MaxOrderNumbers=”2”>

  <OrderLine LineNumber=”1” SubLineNumber=”1”/>

  <OrderLine LineNumber =”2” SubLineNumber =”1”/>

 </OrderLines>

</Order>
```

i tried below  code can you tell  anybody this  right way for  converting xml to  xslt ya not

```
<xsl:for-each select="Order">

  <tr>

  <td><xsl:value-of select="OrderName"/></td>

  <td><xsl:value-of select="1234567890"/></td>

  </tr>

</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="OrderLines">

   <tr>

  <td><xsl:value-of select="MAxOrderNumbers"/></td>

  <td><xsl:value-of select="2"/></td>

  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="OrderLine/LineNumber">

  <tr>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="LineNumber"/></td>

  <td><xsl:value-of select="1"/></td>

  </tr>

</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="OrderLine/SubLineNumber">

  <tr>

  <td><xsl:value-of select="SubLineNumber"/></td>

  <td><xsl:value-of select="1"/></td>

  </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

```
 <tr>

  <td><xsl:value-of select="LineNumber"/></td>

  <td><xsl:value-of select="2"/></td>

  </tr>

</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="OrderLine/SubLineNumber"> <tr>

   <td><xsl:value-of select="SubLineNumber"/></td>

   <td><xsl:value-of select="1"/></td>
   </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: hey anybody can me  tell how  we can do XSLT Conversion

Comment: Have you done your homework? Please post some codes that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

In situations where you only want to transform part of your XSLT, it is usually best to start off with the XSLT [identity template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

On its own it copies all the nodes and attributes as-is, meaning you only need to write templates for the parts you wish to change.

You are changing attributes here, so a template to change `OrderNo` to `OrderName` would look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="@OrderNo">
    <xsl:attribute name="OrderName">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Similarly templates would therefore be written for `PrimeLineNo` and `SubPrimeNo`.

The only other thing you are doing is adding a new attribute to the `OrderLines` element, so you would have a template to match the `OrderLines` element, and just add a new element like so:

```
<xsl:template match="OrderLines">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="MaxOrderNumbers">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(OrderLine)" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In fact, you could simplify this with [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates). This template would also work

```
<xsl:template match="OrderLines">
    <OrderLines MaxOrderNumbers="{count(OrderLine)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </OrderLines>
</xsl:template>
```

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OrderLines">
        <OrderLines MaxOrderNumbers="{count(OrderLine)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </OrderLines>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@OrderNo">
        <xsl:attribute name="OrderName">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@PrimeLineNo">
        <xsl:attribute name="LineNumber">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@SubLineNo">
        <xsl:attribute name="SubLineNumber">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```